# mysql Find_in_set is better or single query check is better

Tags: php, mysql

i have problem with mysql find_in_set, because in table named menu_table in which:i would like to store following data. But i want to match the value of menu_ids to single menu_id of another table

```
mt_id menu_ids
---------------
 1    4,5,6,
 2    7,8,
 or 
mt_id menu_ids
----------
1      4
2      5
```

then i don't understand how to store the value and which is better solution for checking menu_ids?

Answer (score 2):

Do not store values separated by a comma. It's a bad schema design. I suggest the you design the table like this,

**Menu Table**

- MenuID (PK)
- OtherColumns...

**Other Table**

- MTID (PK)
- OtherColumns...

**Menu_Other table**

- MTID (PK with column MenuID)
- MenuID (FK)

---

Example Records

**Menu Table**

```
MenuID  OtherColumn
1       aaaa
2       bbbb
```

**Other Table**

```
MTID    OtherColumns
1       a   
2       b
3       c
4       d
5       e
6       f
```

**Menu_Other Table**

```
MenuID  MTID    
1       1
1       2
2       3
2       4
2       5
```